# Rewrite a circle's equation to easily see centre and radius

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

$$x^{2}+y^{2}-5x-15y+30=0$$

I'm supposed to rewrite this equation so that you can easily see the centre and radius of the circle. I don't even know where to start. According to Mathematica the centre is $(5/2, 15/2)$ and the radius is $\sqrt{65/2}$.

Comment: Hint:  Add terms to make the x component and y componenet perfect squares and move the constant to the right.  factors of x and y are the centers and square root of the constant to the right of the equation is the center.

Comment: the last word in the previous comment  should be radius, I mistyped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

$$x^2 +y^2 -5x-15y+30 = 0$$
$$x^2 -5x +(\frac{5}{2})^2 +y^2 -15x +(\frac{15}{2})^2 -(\frac{5}{2})^2-(\frac{15}{2})^2+30 = 0$$

$$(x-\frac{5}{2})^2+(y-\frac{15}{2})^2 = \frac{225+25}{4}-30$$

$$(x-\frac{5}{2})^2+(y-\frac{15}{2})^2 =(\sqrt{\frac{65}{2}})^2$$

Center$$ (\frac{5}{2},\frac{15}{2})$$and the radius $$= \sqrt{\frac{65}{2}}$$

Comment: And this method is called "completing the square", if you want to Google it.

Comment: Is it kind of an information?

Answer (score 1):

I will do $x$. Please do $y$.

$$x^2+y^2-5x-15y+30=0$$
$$x^2-5x+25/4-25/4+y^2-15y+30=0$$
$$(x-5/2)^2+y^2-15y+30-25/4=0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

$$\left(x^2-2\cdot\frac{5}{2}x+\frac{25}{4}\right)-\frac{25}{4}+\left(y^2-2\cdot\frac{15}{2}y+\frac{225}{4}\right)-\frac{225}{4}+30=0$$